# How I can parse to float the string data values of a specific column in a dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, parsing

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=dict_kv, columns = header)
df.head()
```

```
Provinces   Confirmed cases Confirmed deaths    Probable deaths
0   Azuay   10658            195                 12
1   Bolívar 2111             66                  12
2   Cañar   2110             83                  7
3   Carchi  3053             104                 1
```

For instance, for this dataframe I only want parse to float the data in the columns:
*Confirmed cases, Confirmed deaths, Probable deaths

I want to improve this conversion:

```
for x in range(1,len(dict_kv[0]),4):
  dict_kv[0][x]=float(dict_kv[0][x])
  dict_kv[0][x+1]=float(dict_kv[0][x+1])
  dict_kv[0][x+2]=float(dict_kv[0][x+2])
```

Comment: I don't understand what  you mean.  You don't "parse" a single token.  You simply convert the values; they appear to be either `int`` or `str` type, either of which is a direct conversion.  Where are you stuck?  Even more, it appears that you have the values in a dict; why not simply convert them in the dict?

Comment: convert those colums values (Confirmed cases, Confirmed deaths, Probable deaths) into floats instead of String.

Comment: Right.  If you don't know how to convert a string to float, repeat your local tutorial on basic data types.  If you don't know how to apply an operation to a DF column, repeat your local tutorial on DF handling.  Neither of these seems to be a Stack Overflow issue.  Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: Because I want to found out if there is a way  to do it directly in dataframes

Comment: PD: The final result of rows, which is renamed to dict_kv (not a dictionary, it is a list), is:
[['AZUAY', '10688', '195', '12'],
 ['BOLÍVAR', '2115', '66', '12'],
 ['CAÑAR', '2153', '83', '7'],
 ['CARCHI', '3058', '104', '1'],
 ['CHIMBORAZO', '2536', '315', '119'],
 ['COTOPAXI', '4588', '283', '61'],

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [pandas.DataFrame.astype()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.3/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html)

```
df = df.astype({"Confirmed cases":'float64', "Confirmed deaths":'float64', "Probable deaths":'float64'})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df[["Confirmed cases", "Confirmed deaths", "Probable deaths"]] = df[["Confirmed cases", "Confirmed deaths", "Probable deaths"]].apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the datatype of a column by using the following:

```py
df.astype(float)
```

Documentation available [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html)